# Open source JDBC-ODBC bridge experience?

Tags: linux, open-source, jdbc, odbc

Does anybody have any experience or recommendations using an open source JDBC-ODBC bridge on Linux that would be helpful for making the decision about whether to use a solution like this or to try to find another way?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com) solutions here --

- [Single-tier JDBC to ODBC Bridge](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/) (client only architecture)
- [Multi-tier JDBC to ODBC Bridge](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-mt/) (client/server architecture)

Comment: I forgot to add the open source requirement when I originally posed the question, so +1 anyway even though this appears to be closed source.